# Не срабатывает событие onload в Safari при асинхронной загрузке "Поделиться"

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Добрый день.

Пример - https://michaeldanilov.github.io/yashare-bug/

Собственно при загрузке всех версий по ссылке в Firefox 50+, Chrome 51+, Яндекс.Браузере 17.7+ срабатывают и события `readystatechange`, и `load`.

С Safari 10.1 (ниже не проверял) же всё не так:
при обычной загрузке (script:src), defer-загрузке (script:src + defer) срабатывают оба события, а если async-загрузке (script:src + async - [что рекомендовано](https://tech.yandex.ru/share/doc/dg/add-docpage/)), то срабатывает только `readystatechange` событие.

Также я сделал app-версию, когда я динамически вставляю скрипт Поделиться, например в React-компоненте, пробрасываю ему какие-то состояния страницы и место, куда нарисовать блок. И там уже не важно async/defer или прочее, `load` не срабатывает, только `readystatechange`.

Я немного поигрался со кодом скрипта, похоже проблема во встроенном `contentloaded.js`, который ломает поведение в Safari.

Comment: Спасибо за образцово сформулированный вопрос, да ещё и с примером! Ближе к выходным постараюсь найти время покопаться в этом вопросе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

История вот какая.

Ещё с тех времён, когда блок поддерживал IE8, для определения события загрузки DOM-дерева в нём используется библиотека [ContentLoaded](https://github.com/dperini/ContentLoaded).

Это библиотека вызывает переданный коллбэк в трёх случаях.

1. Вызвано событие `DOMContentLoaded`.
2. Вызвано событие `readystatechange` и документ находится в состоянии `complete`.
3. Вызвано событие `load`.

При загрузке скрипта синхронно или с указанием `defer` отрабатывает первый сценарий.

При асинхронной загрузке скрипта событие `DOMContentLoaded` срабатывает до того, как загрузится скрипт. Поэтому отрабатывает второй сценарий – `readystatechange` и `complete`.

И тут в дело вступает баг (или особенность?) Safari: если начать асинхронную загрузку скрипта в момент, когда документ уже находится в состоянии `complete`, а событие `load` ещё не вызвано, оно никогда не вызовется!

Минимальный код для воспроизведения бага выглядит так.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Safari insert after readyState == complete</title>
  <script>
    function injectJs() {
        const element = document.createElement('script');
        element.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js';
        document.head.appendChild(element);
    }

    document.addEventListener('readystatechange', e => {
      if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        injectJs();
      }
    });

    window.addEventListener('load', e => console.log(e.type));
  </script>
```

Так что библиотеку мы заменим на более современное [решение](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core/ready.js#L60-L86), и всё будет хорошо.